# Can I get the current user's email address that is logging into Google Calendar on my website?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

So my website has a few features that use Google Calendar. However I want to make sure that whenever the admins are using it, they must use the account that we gave them so that we can organize it easier. Is there a way for me to check what email address the user uses to login to google calendar?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible when using [Google Apps Email Audit API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/).

As stated in the documentation,

> The **Google Apps Email Audit API** allows Google Apps administrators to audit a user's email, email drafts, and archived chats. In addition, a domain administrator can retrieve account login information and download a user's mailbox.

However, please note that it is not used with a Google Apps or Gmail account not hosted by the Google Apps products. And, you must enable API access from the Google Apps Admin console to be able to make any calls to the Google Apps Email Audit API.